# Remove ribbon from outlook window

Tags: c#, com, outlook

Outlook 2010 
We save .msg on the disk and we use COM API's to start the outlook window.

```
MailItem mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(fileName);
```

We don't want our users to click "Reply/Reply All" and give them a read-only view of the message. I know there are some listeners that I can use and cancel these events (ItemEvents_10_Event) but that's not very user friendly.

I would instead like to remove the whole ribbon so that they don't even see this option.

```
SendKeys.Send("^{F1}");
```

Sending control signal just hides it, I want to remove it altogether. (control signals are anyways very unreliable when sent pragmatically.

Any pointers will be really helpful.

-Karephul

Comment: Hiding the ribbon won't make the option unavailable. You're trying to solve the problem the wrong way round.

Comment: @CodyGray I am trying to remove the ribbon so that there is no option to click anything over there.

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem of keyboard shortcuts, the user showing the ribbon again, etc. You're addressing the symptom, not the problem. And only somewhat poorly addressing the symptom. Anyway, no, you can't remove the ribbon entirely. You need to disable the commands you don't want the user executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that this is possible.  It might make more sense to just extract the contents of the message (e.g. using `Subject` and `HTMLBody` or `Body`) and display them in a more appropriate container, such as an IE window.

Comment: we thought about it - but the e-mail reading experience won't be the same. I am surprised that removing the ribbon is not possible.

Comment: Outlook is an email client.  For the vast majority of users, there's no value in making the ribbon be removeable.  It would add a decent bit of work to build and test that behavior, so I would have been pretty surprised if the Outlook team actually spent the time on that feature.

Comment: Looks like its not possible. I finally decided to bind on  ItemEvents_10_Event and do some custom behavior. Not ideal, but works for now.